# SourceTree keeps asking for Kiln authentication (Windows)

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Every couple of minutes, SourceTree creates a popup looking for my Kiln username and password. Clicking cancel closes the window but another immediately appears. I didn't have a Kiln account but I created one just to get rid of this popup. I entered my Kiln username and password into the popup but it just continues to pop up. I've checked the "Remember password" button but that had no effect.

How do I prevent this popup from appearing?

Comment: I have the same exact question and I still waiting for an answer.